# RegEx - Match anything preceded by given characters and then anything

Tags: regex, notepad++, lookbehind

I am trying to replace characters, but can't figure out how to select only them.

Let's say I have this stretch of text. I need to select "non_regd" knowing that it is at some point preceded by "Given title".

```
<title>Given title</title>
<link>http://loremipsum.com/given-title/</link>
<pubDate>Sat, 25 Oct 2014 00:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator><![CDATA[non_regd]]></dc:creator>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://loremipsum.com/given-title/</guid>
<description></description>
```

My idea was

```
(?<=Given title</title>(.*?))non_regd
```

but this is apparently not allowed RegEx.

Any idea? Thanks

Edit: I only use Notepad++ for this. I just need to replace the "non-regd" part with something else. The problem is though, that there are many similar pieces of code in the file, so it needs to be specific in this way.

Comment: An XML Parser should really be used to parse XML, not a RegEx

Comment: ^agreed. Also, what language/regex flavor are you using? Javascript, unlike PCRE or Python or pretty much any other flavor, doesnt support any lookbehinds

Comment: Don't use the assertion. `Given title</title>(.*?)non_regd`

Comment: virtually all regex engine don't support variable length look behinds. Tell us what exactly you want to do with a match if you could get one.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found something that works.

```
Given title</title>.*?\Knon_regd
```

\K does the magic trick. although it is a workaround. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: `\K` makes sense, but trying to match a substring  by itself for a replacement is basically ludicrous. That's why there are capture groups.